# Undefined function 'max' for input arguments of type 'cell'

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to plot bar chart for input data and to add data labels on each bar, when I run the program I got an error as "Undefined function 'max' for input arguments of type 'cell'." my code is...

```
 data = [3 6 2 ;9 5 1];
figure; %// Create new figure
h = bar(data);    %// Create bar plot 
%// Get the data for all the bars that were plotted
x = get(h,'XData');
y = get(h,'YData');
ygap = 0.1;  %// Specify vertical gap between the bar and label
ylim([0 12])
ylimits = get(gca,'YLim');

%// The following two lines have minor tweaks from the original answer
set(gca,'YLim',[ylimits(1),ylimits(2)+0.2*max(y)]);
labels = cellstr(num2str(data'))                                   %//'

for i = 1:length(x) %// Loop over each bar
    xpos = x(i);        %// Set x position for the text label
    ypos = y(i) + ygap; %// Set y position, including gap
    htext = text(xpos,ypos,labels{i});          %// Add text label
    set(htext,'VerticalAlignment','bottom', 'HorizontalAlignment','center')
end
```

**when I give input as "data = [3 6 2 9 5 1]", the program runs fine**

Answer (score 1):

Matlab is a typeless language, so you don't know what type `y` is actually going to be. When you try `data = [3 6 2 9 5 1]` and call `class(y)` you will get `double` as an answer, which in this example is a vector of real numbers `max()` can work on. 
However when you use `data = [3 6 2 ; 9 5 1]`, you get different `y` :

```
>> class(y)

ans =

cell

>> y

y = 

    [1x2 double]
    [1x2 double]
    [1x2 double]

>>
```

Which means `y` is not a vector nor a matrix but a `cell` array that holds together three double vectors. `max()` does not know how to work on `cell` arrays and gives you

> Undefined function 'max' for input arguments of type `cell`

error . You can find more on Matlab data types on http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/data-types_data-types.html

You can fix this error by turning `y` back into a vector, but as your `labels` will also change I will leave you here:

```
data = [3 6 2 ;9 5 1];
figure; %// Create new figure
h = bar(data);    %// Create bar plot 
%// Get the data for all the bars that were plotted
x = get(h,'XData');
y = get(h,'YData');
ygap = 0.1;  %// Specify vertical gap between the bar and label
ylim([0 12])
ylimits = get(gca,'YLim');
y=[y{1} y{2} y{3}]; %works in this particular example
%// The following two lines have minor tweaks from the original answer
set(gca,'YLim',[ylimits(1),ylimits(2)+0.2*max(y)]);
labels = cellstr(num2str(data'))
```

Comment: Alternatively you could use `max` with [`cellfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) and not worry about conversion: `max(cellfun(@max, y))`